# Send RSA public key over socket them import it for encryption [VB .NET]

Tags: vb.net, encryption, rsa

I'm writing that generates public and private key pair, then send the public key over the socket to another programs to be used to encrypt string data.
I'm using RSA in VB.NET and I was able to generate the required keys:

> My public key v+u4Lt4nyLXincU+wbReOTU3nwiTZ7MlFkA7cytLOjuviHrAdnaVAV8+WoFhy9nADGtk1K0OLAE1ZwGzt/kgUw==

My question is: is the public key enough for encryption by other users? and if so, how can I import it to RSA parameters to encrypt data?

Edit:

I used the following code in an attempt to import the public key but it failed:

```
Dim Parameters As New RSAParameters
Parameters.Modulus = encoder.GetBytes(publicKey)
RSA.ImportParameters(Parameters)
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: is the public key enough for encryption by other
>   users?

The answer is as so often: It depends.

The way you describe your proposed protocol this would be widely open to man-in-the-middle-attacks. Eve could just intercept the message on the wire and replace the key by her own.

From a theoretical point of view, it is sufficient to encrypt data. However, to be useful in real world scenarios, you have to use symmetric encryption as well.

So here is my advice:
Don't do your own protocols if you have to ask such questions. Never. Not once. **Use Well known, established technology like TLS!**

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This is a basic program. later I will be using symmetric as well as private key encryption for authentication. for now I just need to know how to import the keys into RSA parameters for successful encryption/decryption.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar project in VB.net, you will not be able to send messages of a large length because if you are using 2048bit RSA, the maximum size of data you would be able to send would be 245 bytes. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/rsa-maximum-bytes-to-encrypt-comparison-to-aes-in-terms-of-security

I used the RSA public key so each client would use AES encryption and pass their own keys which are encrypted with RSA, the server would then decrypt the key and use that to resolve data. This uses both asymmetric(RSA) and symmetric encryption(AES). Here is a link with a useful video that explains this when I was doing this project. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6H_9l9N3IXU&t=271s

The way I imported the keys was using the .toXMLString and .fromXMLString in the RSA CryptoServiceProvider. Here is a great link explaining it, probably doing a better job that I could. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found this page that was very useful for me [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=102212&seqNum=6)

Also I found that I was making the mistake of converting the encrypted byte array to string after encryption then back to byte array just before decryption. The last byte array didn't have the same size as the original.